# On a KDE4 Debian installation, where does the QtCore library install to?

Tags: debian, kde4, cmake, qt4

I have installed every possible package that could have to do with QtCore (I think), but the QtCore library is nowhere to be found. Not in `/usr/lib`, not in `/usr/local/lib`, not in `usr/include`... you get the idea. Still, CMAKE gives the location of `QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE` as `QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND` and since it doesn't show up where I look, I can't tell it otherwise. I have installed qmake, libqtcore4, libqt4-dev and several other packages. To add insult to injury, *I am using the Qt4 version of Cmake.* Am I simply missing the *real* QtCore package or is the library somewhere incredibly non-obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian, most libraries are installed in an architecture-specific path; assuming you're using a typical 64-bit PC (the `amd64` architecture in Debian), you'll find `libQtCore.so` and friends in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

To find this out generically, you can use `dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH` (from the [`dpkg-dev`](https://tracker.debian.org/dpkg-dev) package). When you're looking for files, check out [`apt-file`](https://tracker.debian.org/apt-file): it can search for files in all available packages in Debian, and `apt-file search libQtCore` finds `libqtcore4` and `libqt4-dev` in seconds.